# Joining multiple lines into a single one with the same ID

Tags: sql, rows

The problem appears when I do a query on a couple of columns (of a survey) because I want the output point to a single ID, instead of the query divides the output for each response of that the id provides.

Original query

```
select distinct _PanelistaId_,
(case when cancl_seg_vida_mr = '4' then '1' end) as cancl_seg_vida_mr,
(case when prop_seg_med_mr = '5' then '1' end) as prop_seg_med_mr
FROM [NQ_Mexico].[dbo].[tabla_sr_mr_values] 
where _PanelistaId_ = '100177354'
group by _PanelistaId_, cancl_seg_vida_mr, prop_seg_med_mr
```

the outpus is :

```
_PanelistaId_   cancl_seg_vida_mr   prop_seg_med_mr
100177354         NULL          NULL
100177354         NULL          1
100177354         1             NULL
```

But the output I want is this one:

```
_PanelistaId_   cancl_seg_vida_mr   prop_seg_med_mr
100177354           1               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select _PanelistaId_,
       max(case when cancl_seg_vida_mr = '4' then '1' end) as cancl_seg_vida_mr,
       max(case when prop_seg_med_mr = '5' then '1' end) as prop_seg_med_mr
from [NQ_Mexico].[dbo].[tabla_sr_mr_values] 
where _PanelistaId_ = '100177354'
group by _PanelistaId_;
```